# js function call help needed

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

i have the code as shown below,
this is the html part.

```
    <html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    <script src="regi.js" ></script>
</head>
<body class="regbody">
    <form align="center" method="POST" action="submit()" name="regform">
    <div id="regpgdiv">
        <span class="indextext">Fill in the details below to get registered! </span><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="regfname" id="ip" value="Enter name" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter name') { this.value = ''; }"  onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Enter name'; }" /> <br><br>
        <input type="text" name="reguname" id="ip" value="Enter Desired Username" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter Desired Username') { this.value = ''; }"  onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Enter Desired Username'; }" /> <br><br>
        <input type="password" name="regpwd" id="ip" value="Select Password" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Select Password') { this.value = ''; }"  onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Select Password'; }" /> <br><br>
        <input type="password" name="cregpwd" id="ip" value="Re-enter Password" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Re-enter Password') { this.value = ''; }"  onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Re-enter Password'; }" /> <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" id="credsub" >
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

and the js code is below for the Submit function

```
function Submit(){

var fname = document.form.regfname.value,
uname= document.form.reguname.value,

fpassword = document.form.regpwd.value,
cfpassword= document.form.cregpwd.value;

if( uname == "" || uname == "Enter Desired Username")
{
 document.form.reguname.focus() ;
 document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the username";
 return false;
}
  if( fname == "" || fname == "Enter name")
     {
      document.form.regfname.focus() ;
    document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the first name";
     return false;
  }  



  if(fpassword == "" || fpassword == "Select password" )
     {
   document.form.regpwd.focus();
   document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the password";
   return false;
  }

    if (!(cfpassword.equals(fpassword)) )
     {  
    document.form.cregpwd.focus();
     document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "doesnt match";
      return false;

     }

       if(fname != '' &&  fpassword != '' && cfpassword != '' && uname!= ''){
     document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "form submitted successfully";
    }

    }
```

when i click the regiter button, it says this webpage has npt been found.
i am new to javascript and need help. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**Yet Another Update** - I realised there are errors in your Javascript code for referencing DOM objects (as well as a typo in your validation logic), below are the working modified code. In short, I have added `id`'s to the form elements for referencing, and in your validation logic, you should be check `Select Password` instead of `Select password`.

#### The HTML form

```
<form align="center" method="POST" action="TARGET-PAGE-TO-HANDLE-DATA" name="regform" id="regform" onsubmit="return Submit()">
    <div id="regpgdiv">
        <span class="indextext">Fill in the details below to get registered! </span><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="regfname" id="fname" value="Enter name" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter name') { this.value = ''; }"  onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Enter name'; }" /> <br><br>
        <input type="text" name="reguname" id="uname" value="Enter Desired Username" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter Desired Username') { this.value = ''; }"  onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Enter Desired Username'; }" /> <br><br>
        <input type="password" name="regpwd" id="regpwd" value="Select Password" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Select Password') { this.value = ''; }"  onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Select Password'; }" /> <br><br>
        <input type="password" name="cregpwd" id="cregpwd" value="Re-enter Password" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Re-enter Password') { this.value = ''; }"  onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value = 'Re-enter Password'; }" /> <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" id="credsub" >    
    </div>
</form>
```

#### JS

```
function Submit() {

var fname = document.getElementById("fname");
var uname= document.getElementById("uname");

var fpassword = document.getElementById("regpwd");
var cfpassword= document.getElementById("cregpwd");

    if (uname.value == "" || uname.value == "Enter Desired Username") {
        uname.focus() ;
        document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the username";
        return false;
    }

    if (fname.value == "" || fname.value == "Enter name") {
        fname.focus();
        document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the first name";
        return false;
    }  

    if (fpassword.value == "" || fpassword.value == "Select Password" ) {
        fpassword.focus();
        document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "enter the password";
        return false;
    }

    if (cfpassword.value != fpassword.value) {  
        cfpassword.focus();
        document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "doesnt match";
        return false;
    }

    if (fname.value != '' &&  fpassword.value != '' && cfpassword.value != '' && uname.value != '') {
        document.getElementById("errorBox").innerHTML = "form submitted successfully";
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Updated** - Thanks [Useless Code](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778975/useless-code) for the helpful suggestion, I have modified the code accordingly to use `onSubmit` instead of the `onClick` event.

Your HTML code should be:

```
<form align="center" method="POST" action="TARGET-PAGE-TO-HANDLE-DATA" name="regform" onsubmit="return Submit();">
```

The `action` attribute specifies the target page to handle the form data. And the `onSubmit` attribute specifies the Javascript function to be executed when the submit button in the form is clicked.

Comment: It would be better to put the call to `Submit` in an `onSubmit` event on the form instead of the `onClick` of the submit button. It's been a while since I've dealt with events on forms but I'm pretty sure putting it on the `onClick` of the button will submit the form regardless of validation in the `Submit` function.

Comment: @UselessCode That's a great point! I have modified the code accordingly, thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in a comment, `onsubmit` is much more appropriate in this situation. The JavaScript placed in an `onclick` attribute will fire when the HTML element is clicked, but for a form you actually want code that executes on submission. So:

```
<form align="center" method="POST" action="self" name="regform" onsubmit="Submit()">
```

would be closer. However, it's generally considered poor practice to use the "on" attributes to handle events in JavaScript. For one, it mixes your JavaScript with your semantic HTML, which can be make debugging harder an mixes separate concerns. But it also means that whatever you use in the "on" attributes has to be in the global scope, which can become problematic fast. Consider if you had multiple forms on the page; how would you designate the submit functions for each?

A more solid way of performing this is to put your function in an event listener, e.g.:

```
function Submit() {
    // rest of your code here
}

document.form.regform.addEventListener('submit', Submit, false);
```

Here the addEventListener method takes an event type string first and a function to execute when that event occurs second. The MDN article on [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) has more.